# Facing problem in a Leetcode practice problem related to String

Tags: java, string, algorithm, data-structures

Click [HERE](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-repeating-character-replacement/) for the problem link.

**Problem Statement** - You are given a string s and an integer k. You can choose any character of the string and change it to any other uppercase English character. You can perform this operation at most k times.

Return the length of the longest substring containing the same letter you can get after performing the above operations.

Example 1:

Input: s = "ABAB", k = 2;
Output: 4

Explanation: Replace the two 'A's with two 'B's or vice versa.

Example 2:

Input: s = "AABABBA", k = 1;
Output: 4

Explanation: Replace the one 'A' in the middle with 'B' and form "AABBBBA".
The substring "BBBB" has the longest repeating letters, which is 4.

Constraints:

1 <= s.length <= 105
s consists of only uppercase English letters.
0 <= k <= s.length

**MY APPROACH** -

I have been trying to solve this problem since today, but I am lacking some knowledge. I am trying to solve this problem with the approach inspired by **VOYER's MOORE MAJORITY VOTING ALGORITHM**.

- My intuition is that suppose the first character will have the max count, then if we find another character then decrease the value of ptr and increase the count along with storing the value in max.
- if at some point, ptr == 0, and there are still characters remaining then make the current character as the max_character and repeat the same process. Similar to the majority voting algorithm.
- But, I am making some mistakes, I don't know what but I'm really close and want to solve this problem using this approach.

```
class Solution {
    public int characterReplacement(String s, int k) {
        
        int count = 0;
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
        int ptr = k;  
        char ch = ' ';
        
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            
            // if at sometime, ptr equals zero then count will also be zero
            if(count == 0){
                ch = s.charAt(i);
                count = 1;
            }
            else{
                if(s.charAt(i) == ch){
                    count++;
                    max = Math.max(count, max);
                }
                else{
                    if(ptr == 0){
                        ch = s.charAt(i);
                        ptr = k;
                        count = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                    ptr--;
                    count++;
                    max = Math.max(count, max);
                }
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

I hope, I am able to explain my approach clearly, English is not my mother tongue, so grammatical mistakes can happen. And also, I know the approach to solve this problem using hashmap, but want to solve it using this approach.

Comment: Please [edit] and improve your question so that it is clearer, more focused and easier to answer. 1) Please improve your question title so that it summarizes your actual problem. Your current title tells us little of use. 2) You mention that your code is having problems but you tell us nothing about what specific problems you may be having.

Comment: Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask and answer Homework questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: Please provide a few sample inputs, current outputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Also, is this class supposed to be "runnable", in other words, is it supposed to have a main method, or does that lie in another class? Either way, please show it.

Comment: "Click HERE for the problem link." while links are nice as *additional* information, readers can't be *forced* to read linked content to understand the question because links tend to break. When the do question/answer becomes unclear and not very useful for others. That is why we *require* from posts to include *all necessary information* needed understand it *in the post itself*.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback, I'll definitely keep these feedbacks in mind and will ask good questions with good explanations in the future. I am in a very bad mood while posting this question because I'm not getting any source for help and it would be easier for me to explain my problem in my mother tongue. Thank you all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error in that once you exhaust `k` the code then needs to return to the first replacement index to resume the search.

Your implementation simply resumes the search from the last index where the `k` is exhausted.

Using the first failed case (`characterReplacement("BABABBA", 1)`) the posted code finds these subsequences (found subsequence in bold - first line is test case):

BABABBA
**BBB**ABBA
BAB**AA**BA
BABAB**BB**

when it should find:

BABABBA
**BBB**ABBA
B**AAA**BBA
BA**BBBB**A           **<-- OP code misses this one** 
BAB**AA**BA
BABA**BBB**
BABABB**A**

To fix this you should first change your for loop to a while loop:

```
i = 0;
while (i < s.length()) {
}
```

And introduce an index variable `lastStart` which indicates the beginning of the subsequence on first mismatch:

```
int lastStart = 0;
```

And reset it to 0 as long as there is a sequence match:

```
if (count == 0) {
    // .. existing code
    lastStart = 0;
}
```

And reset the loop variable when replacement is exhausted subsequence mismatch and maintain `lastStart` on **first** subsequence mismatch.

```
else {
    if (ptr == 0) {
        // existing code
        i = lastStart;
    }
    if (ptr == k) lastStart = i;
    // existing code
}
```

Results:

| Test | OP | Actual | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `characterReplacement("ABAB", 2)` | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| `characterReplacement("AABABBA", 1)` | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| `characterReplacement("BABABBA", 1))` | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| `characterReplacement("BABABCBABBB", 2)` | 5 | 7 | 7 |

---

Full code:

```
public int characterReplacement(String s, int k) {
    
    int count = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; 
    int ptr = k;  
    char ch = ' ';
    int i = 0;
    int lastStart = 0;
    
    while (i < s.length())
    {
        
        
        // if at sometime, ptr equals zero then count will also be zero
        if(count == 0){
            ch = s.charAt(i);
            count = 1;
            lastStart = 0;
        }
        else{
            if(s.charAt(i) == ch){
                count++;
                max = Math.max(count, max);
            }
            else{
                if(ptr == 0){
                    ch = s.charAt(i);
                    ptr = k;
                    count = 0;
                    i = lastStart;
                    continue;
                }
                if (ptr == k) lastStart = i;
                ptr--;
                count++;
                max = Math.max(count, max);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for your help, I really needed some help regarding this approach as I am in the learning phase, and google, and StackOverflow are the only sources to clear my doubts. Thank you! Have a good day.